# Groovy reverse() to reverse a string throws error

Tags: groovy

Wanted to represent the version which is in big Endian in this format 'B.2.00.4C' but I came up with the below snippet in groovy

```
def version = '4C00020B'
byte[] byteVersion = version.decodeHex()
byte[] byteReversed = byteVersion.reverse()
def versionStr = byteReversed.collect { String.format('%02X', it) }.join('.')
println versionStr
```

which throws below error.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [B.reverse() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: every(), every(groovy.lang.Closure) at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)
```

Also my solution doesn't remove zero if there's a non zero value in each byte exists.
How can I fix the error and get the output in the format I wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reverse method on arrays, you'll need to convert it to a list

```
byte[] byteReversed = byteVersion.toList().reverse()
```

Then, to get the format you want, you'll need to drop the `02` from the formatting, but handle `0` separately

```
def versionStr = byteReversed.collect { 
    it == 0 ? '00' : String.format('%X', it) 
}.join('.')
```